# Membership Role Provider doesn't work with custom connection string?

Tags: asp.net, sql, membership, provider

plz help with one issue.
I have Membership configured with IIS7, tables for it located in my own database, created with aspnet_regsql utility, and I am using custom connection string to access it.

This is part of web.config related to Membership :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Server=CORESERVER\SQLExpress;Database=Shop;User ID=Tema;Password=Matrix" name="CustomSqlConnection" />
</connectionStrings>
<profile enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="CustomSqlConnection" />
      </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="CustomSqlConnection" />
      </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="CustomSqlMemberProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomSqlMemberProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="CustomSqlConnection" enablePasswordReset="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" applicationName="/" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
      </providers>
</membership>
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="login.aspx" name="WebShopAuthentication" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/" requireSSL="false" defaultUrl="~/admin/default.aspx" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

And ... Forms authorization, getting user and his membership info is OK.
But ... getting roles is always FALSE.

```
MembershipUser userData = Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);    // OK !!! IT IS GREAT :)
var a = new RolePrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);
var aa = a.getRoles();  // {string[0]} - EMPTY!!!
var b = Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator", "Administrator");  // FALSE!!!
var c = Roles.Providers["CustomSqlRoleProvider"].GetAllRoles();  // {string[0]} - EMPTY!!!
var d = Roles.IsUserInRole(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, "Administrator"); // FALSE!!!
var e = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator"); // FALSE !!!
```

WHYYYY???

What am i doing wrong???

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question but have you actually created any roles and assigned them to current user?

Comment: Actually yes. There are : 1 provider with overridden connection string pointed to my DB, 4 roles - Administrator, Customer, Manager, User, and 3 users named Administrator, Manager, Customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that i didn't add applicationName parameter to web.config correctly - after adding i should restart IIS and if needed recreate roles.
This is final version of web.config :

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="CustomSqlRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="CustomSqlConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to refine ... authorization works fine and uses roles correctly. Another part of my web.config :

```
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
      <pages styleSheetTheme="Admin" theme="Admin">
      </pages>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <allow roles="Administrator" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="ThemeName" value="Admin" />
    </appSettings>
</location>
```

And then in code is used :

```
Membership.ValidateUser(userName.Text, userPassword.Text) // AND IT WORKS - USER IS LOGGED IN
```